# Does $\Omega \in$ $\mathcal{F}$ mean that rules 2 and 3 are satisfied if $\Omega$ countable?

Tags: measure-theory

No need to say I'm not a mathematician. This question came about because I was trying to explain to myself why the three rules for a $\sigma$-algebra are necessary for a measure (in my case a probability). My reasoning went at follows ($\Omega$ is the originating set):

Rule 1, that $\emptyset$ and $\Omega$ be in the collection of subsets of $\Omega$, is needed because if $\Omega$ is not there then rule 2 (complements) can't be satisfied. And $\emptyset$ must be there as $\Omega^c$ (and vv). Rule 1 is there to make rules 2 (closure under complement) and rule 3 (closure under countable unions) possible.

When I got to that point I realized I'd convinced myself that rule 1 made rules 2 and 3 redundant  for a countable $\Omega$. Am I wrong? I'll be astonished if I'm right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a bit confused about your question as it seems that you wish to deduce rules $2$ and $3$ from rule $1$ in the case that $\Omega$ is countable. That is not the case as if you let $\Omega=\{1,2\}$, and then $\mathcal{F}=\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{1,2\}\}$ will satisfy rule $1$, but not rule $2$ as it is not closed under complements since $\{1\}^c\notin\mathcal{F}$, so you can't deduce rules $2$ and $3$ from rule $1$ in the case that $\Omega$ is countable. I think your confusion might stems from how it appears that $\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$ satisfies the axioms, and I will note that what you call rule $1$ can actually be weakened (or changed) in the following manners (note that the following works for a general $\Omega$).

However, it is true that rule $1$ is a bit redundant as you do have complements from rule $2$. Thus, what we can do is replace rule $1$ with the following rule $1'$ which states that $\Omega\in\mathcal{F}$. Then if we take the definition of a sigma-algebra to use rule $1'$ instead of rule $1$, then we still get a sigma-algebra using complements since if $\Omega\in\mathcal{F}$, then $\Omega^c=\emptyset\in\mathcal{F}$. Thus, we have the empty set.

The only reason rule $1$ exists is to rule out the case of the $\mathcal{F}=\emptyset$ (that is you must actually have something that you wish to measure in your sigma-algebra). You can see this as follows. Let us replace rule $1$ with rule $1''$ where rule $1''$ is that we require $\mathcal{F}$ to be non-empty. Then we can deduce rule $1'$ (and hence rule $1$) as follows. Since $\mathcal{F}$ is non-empty there is some $Y\in \mathcal{F}$, so $Y\cup Y^c=\Omega\in \mathcal{F}$ (this uses complements (rule $2$) and unions (rule $3$)).

I hope this clears up the confusion you were having.

Comment: thank you, yes  it does in a way, but I wonder if it highlights some deeper confusion in my thinking. You say $\{1\}^c$ $\notin \mathcal{F}$ but it is in $\Omega$ which is in $\mathcal{F}$. Does it have to be in the collection as separate set apart from $\Omega$? If yes, then I have to think about why, If not, then I'm not crazy I just may have phrased my question poorly. I wasn't thinking you could deduce 2, and 3, just that if 1 then you could be sure 2 and 3 ``could'' be satisfied. But your comment about the reason for rule 1 gave me a twinge. Why both, why not just $\Omega$?

Comment: Mmm. I take back my comment. Your first paragraph clearly says that \{2\} must be in $\mathcal{F}$ as a separate set. Sorry for not reading it more carefully. Now I have to ponder why---there's a nuance to 'collection' that I'm missing, but now that I know what I'm looking for I'm halfway there. Thanks again.

Comment: Remember that $\mathcal{F}$ is a subset of the power set of $\Omega$, so it is a set of subsets of $\Omega$, but there is a notion of a sigma-algebra generated by a set which is the smallest sigma-algebra containing it (in practice it is just all the sets that you can get from combining complements and countable unions). For example, the Borel sigma-algebra is the sigma-algebra generated by open sets, even though $\{0\}$ is not an open set it is in the Borel sigma-algebra as it is the countable intersection of $(\frac{-1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$ (which you can cook up through unions and complements).

Comment: Well now I feel compelled to retract my retraction. Direct question: does $\{1\}^c$ need to lbe explicitly and separately listed in the $\sigma$-algebra (see my first response)? If yes, how is $\mathcal{P}(\Omega),\emptyset)$ a $\sigma$-algebra - $\Omega$ is in $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ but it's not listed explicitly, just as the case above.

Comment: Yes, the complement needs to be explicitly listed in the sigma-algebra. So $\mathcal{F}$ is a set of subsets of $\Omega$, so $\mathcal{F}\subset\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$. It might be confusing as it is a set of sets, so we require this set of sets to satisfy these rules. Thus, we have that $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ is a sigma-algebra (as it will satisfy all the rules), and so will $\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$. These are the trivial sigma-algebras.  I am not sure what you mean when you say $\mathcal{P}(\Omega),\emptyset)$? If you mean $\{\mathcal{P}(\Omega),\emptyset\}$ this is not a sigma-algebra on $\Omega$

Comment: This is because $\{\mathcal{P}(\Omega),\emptyset\}$ is not a subset of $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$, as if $\Omega=\{1\}$, then this would be $\{\{\emptyset,\{1\}\},\emptyset\}$ which is not a subset of $\{\emptyset,\{1\}\}=\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$. (Since there is a difference between the power set and the set containing the powerset).